# How can I get the rows for each table without picking up the embedded tables rows?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using `Nokogiri` and `ruby`, and I'm trying to get the information from the table at the following link: [roster](http://www.goairforcefalcons.com/sports/m-footbl/mtt/afa-m-footbl-mtt.html).

In the past I've used the "id" field for the table I want to use, but since I want to protect against them changing that id in the future and breaking my code I want to identify the table by assuming things about it's attributes.  Such as, the table has an unordinary number of rows (`<tr>`), and assuming it would almost always have 4 or more columns.

The problem I'm having here is when I use the following code to pull back all tables in the web page and then look for the one with 80+ rows, it counts the child table's rows, when I'd like to only count the immediate children's rows.

```
tables = document.css("table")
tables.each do |table|
  tables.each { |table| puts "#{table.css('tr').count}" }
end
```

Output for this would be...

```
202
135
109
22
19
1
0
```

There should actually be only one table here that is 100+ rows.  But because the document embeds tables within tables it's returning counts for all the `<tr>` elements within the table including the embedded tables.  How can I change my selector to only return the immediate children `<tr>` count from each table?

Comment: Why would you assume that the number of columns is constant if the ID might change? Page scraping is by nature less future proof than a versioned API - develop for the now.

Comment: Answering your question - you could try `table.css('> tr').count`, since `>` is immediate children selector.

Comment: I guess if you really had to it would be a better idea to look at the column header TH elements as these should tell you what the content of the table is.

Comment: @max, because there are ~ 1300 sites that share this same format for tables and I don't want to have to check everyone multiple times over the years to see if the id has changed.  I'm assuming they won't have more than one table at 80+ rows on the same page - as I've yet to see one.  The columns might not be necessary - just where I'm at currently - might remove it.

Comment: @max, can't look at just "th"'s because some of the sites use "td" even though they're headers.  I have something else already setup to determine if a row is a header row or not, and identifying it.

Comment: @YaroHolodiuk, tried that and it seems to return "0" for each table.  I'll continue to experiment with that though - I wasn't aware of that `>` for immediate children.

Comment: You might want `> tbody > tr` for those, or cover both with `> tr,> tbody tr`